# Vertical-aligning title beside a div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm new to HTML/CSS and I still have difficulties with vertical alignment, although I have read several articles on this topic.

Consider the following code.

```css
header {
    display: flex;
}

header div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: grey;
}

header h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div></div>
        <h1>My title here</h1>
    </header>
</body>
```

What I am trying to achieve is this:

[image: expected-result]

I have tried the techniques described [here](https://codepen.io/edge0703/pen/iHJuA) but I still don't manage to get this result. What is the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `align-items: center;` on your `header`

`vertical-align: middle;` and `display: inline-block;` not needed on `h1`

```css
header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

header div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: grey;
}

header h1 {
    background-color: orange;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div></div>
    <h1>My title here</h1>
</header>
```